# To display API response inside the dropdown in angular

Tags: angular

```
{{data.role}}
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Role</mat-label>
       <mat-select >
          <mat-option>selected</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value] = "role">
               {{role.viewValue}}
          </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

`{{data.role}}` Which i have mentioned is the response from API. 
 How to display it in the drop-down?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206394/discussion-on-question-by-chethan-gs-to-display-api-response-inside-the-dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

Store your response in a variable in .ts file.

```
rolesdata = []; // define variable

this.rolesdata = response.data.roles; // store response in variable

rolesdata = [{value: 'ADMIN', viewValue: 'Admin'},
         {value: 'STAFF', viewValue: 'Staff'}]; // for e.g. our variable have this data

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Role</mat-label>
           <mat-select >
              <mat-option>selected</mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let role of rolesdata " [value] = "{{role.value}}">
                   {{ role.viewValue }}
              </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```